# convert the output of PinField.getPassword() to string

Tags: java, swing, tostring, getpasswd

```
        if ("Submit".equals(cmd)) { //Process the password.
    String UserNameInput=UserName.getText();
    ///////////////////////////////ERROR Pin when printed shows error/////////////////////////////
    char[] PinInput = PinField.getPassword();
    String pinInput=PinInput.toString();
            //for debugging , print PinInput , but it prints garbage
    System.out.println("Pin entered is "+PinInput);
            //pinInput has garabage instead of the Pin that was entered
            //so the function isPasswordCorrect fails to verify UserName & Pin
    if (isPasswordCorrect(UserNameInput,pinInput)) 
              {
               //some tasks
              }
         }
            boolean isPasswordCorrect(String Username,String Pin)
            {
             //verify username & pin 
            }
```

I need to convert the PinInput from character array to String, so that I can use  the function isPasswordCorrect() . When I use toString() method , it produces garbage value , what should I do to convert 
the value of PinInput to String  ?

Comment: Please consider up-voting answers you found helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the String API, there is a constructor that accepts a char array.

Comment: Thanks , I found it 
public String(char[] value)

Answer (score 4):

@camickr is right. That's not garbage; `pinField.getPassword().toString()` shows the address of the `char[]`, e.g. `[C@fd54d6`.

Addendum: `String.valueOf(array)` or `new String(array)` will convert the result of [`getPassword()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword%28%29) to a `String`, but this thwarts the security benefit of returning a `char[]`. Consider keeping the value local and following the API guidelines: "it is recommended that the returned character array be cleared after use by setting each character to zero."

Comment: just asking for knowledge (as I got the answer ), is there a way to convert that cha[] array  to String  ?

Comment: and the String.valueOf(array) method simply uses "new String(array)". It is a convenience method.